# Restrict AlertDialog Builder to two lines max in Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code:

`AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppDialogTheme);
        b.setTitle(R.string.opt_out_dialog_title);
        b.setMessage(R.string.opt_out_dialog_message);
b.show();`

My String: `R.string.opt_out_dialog_message` displays sometimes two lines and sometimes three lines within the dialog. I'm wondering if there is a way to restrict it or fix it to a 2 lines max?

Comment: How about if the size exceeds a certain number of chars , then 'the string'+... , so it won't exceed the particular 2 line, but it wont show the entire Title as well

Comment: AlertDialog not provides any customization for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom view and set it to your dialog by `setContentView`.
Or you can try this though it's not official(might not work in all OS, device):

```
Dialog dlg = b.show();
TextView tv = (TextView) dlg.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
tv.setMaxLines(2);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why wouldn't is work on all  OS, devices? Can you explain plz.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin It's a mess. Some devices have their own launchers, like MIUI for xiaomi  or Oxygen OS for One plus, and even the normal code that works well on other devices crashes in these devices, so it's obvious!

Comment: it assumes there is a TextView called `message` somewhere in the dialog, but as OBX said its a mess, some devices might have their own implementation that uses a different layout. .. imho better to create your own custom dialog class to be certain the layout is what you are expecting.

Comment: @Minhtdh It works ! After debugging, when we set the `TextView tv = (TextView) dlg.findViewById(android.R.id.message);` tv is automatically retrieving the message of the Dialog, then setting it to 2 lines as far as max is actually doing the job.

Comment: @OBX Regarding 'might not work in all OS, device", can we put an "if condition" where we check whether it's the workable OS or not?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin by default, android use `android.R.id.message` as id for the message text in AlertDialog but in some OS, they might rewrite the AlertDialog methods and break that logic, but I think not many OS do that, normally, they just override the layout.
@RedaM you can add a null check for `tv`, I just want to warning that this is a kind of hacky way.